# Android: How to make, buttons and checkbox inside each box in a grid?

Tags: android

I need a grid view, and inside each box, in the grid, I need to insert buttons and check box.
What are my options?
--> I could not insert buttons + checkboxes  by using gridView 
--> I tried drawing in canvas, got the grid, but couldnot insert buttons...
Any suggestions??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)?  You can even give each cell a border if you want to see the lines.

Comment: May I ask how? ...I want three square in each row, and each square should contain 3 buttons, 1 checkbox, and 1 text.

Comment: For that you might have a LinearLayout with the orientation set to horizontal in each square of the table.  Maybe it would help if you attached a sketch of what you want.

Comment: this is what I am trying to make : (I just started to post ot htis forum so it doesnot allow me to attach the picture in the thread, I've listed to link to the layout i want to make :) https://picasaweb.google.com/kevindai510/Grid#5576392219018059554

Comment: Yeah, you would just have to use a layout inside each of the cells.  A lot of designing a UI in Android (or Swing, or GTK, or any other toolkit that isn't a wysiwyg) involves nesting layouts inside other layouts.